# Library for noise reduction?

Tags: c#, audio, noise-reduction

I am currently doing a project capturing audio stream from microphone.
The stream I captured was full of background noise. I am wondering if there is library provided for removing the noise.

If not, what kinds of algorithm I should look for?

Comment: `NAudio` probably has something for you

Comment: NAudio is a great library, but seems it does not provide noise suppression.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found a good library for audio noise reduction. However [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) is a really good open source command line sound processing utility. Check out their [documentation page](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), specifically **noiseprof** and **noisered**.

What I would suggest doing to integrate it into your application, is to take the SoX executable and make it an [embedded resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) in your application. Then whenever you need to perform noise reduction, extract the resource to a temporary directory and call [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in order to execute SoX.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there anyway I can use mp4 with SoX

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what kind of noise you have. Some noise can be removed by simple frequency filtering, in which case what you need is an equalizer. Found one for you [here](http://code.google.com/p/practicesharp/downloads/detail?name=NAudioEqualizer.zip&can=2&q=)

Commercial libraries also exist, here's one called [Audiolab](http://www.mitov.com/products/audiolab)